# copying of type struct memory memory to storage not yet supported

Tags: solidity, mapping, struct

I am working on creating a basic voting smart contract.
But when assigning Question obj in the map, I'm getting this error:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Voting {
    struct Question {
        uint256 questionId;
        Option[] options;
    }

    struct Option {
        uint256 optionId;
        string optionValue;
    }

    // map(questionId => Question)
    mapping(uint256 => Question) public mapQuestions;

    function addQuestion(string memory _option1) public {
        Question memory quest;
        quest.questionId = 1;
        quest.options[0] = Option(1, _option1);

        mapQuestions[quest.questionId] = quest;
    }
}
```

When compiling, I'm getting this error:

```
copying of type struct Voting.Option memory[] memory to storage not yet supported
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Arrays and mappings are only allocated to storage right now, and when you create Question in memory you try to allocate the array inside to memory. You would usually get a reference onto the struct from a mapping and work with it like that:

```
function addQuestion(string calldata _option1) public {
    uint _id = 1;
    Question storage quest = mapQuestions[_id];
    quest.questionId = _id;
    quest.options.push(Option(_id, _option1));
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thanks @Kostiantyn for providing a simplistic yet elegant solution.